# Is there more efficient way of multiplying byte array?

Tags: go, bson

I developed a Golang package [BESON](https://github.com/GoblinBear/beson-go) for doing operation of big number.

The [Multiply](https://github.com/GoblinBear/beson-go/blob/master/helper/misc.go#L266) operation code:

```golang
func Multiply(a []byte, b []byte) {
    ans := make([]byte, len(a) + len(b))
    bits := nbits(b)

    var i uint
    for i = bits - 1; int(i) >= 0; i-- {
        byteNum := i >> 3
        bitNum := i & 7

        LeftShift(ans, 1, 0)
        if (b[byteNum] & (1 << bitNum)) > 0 {
            Add(ans, a)
        }
    }
    copy(a, ans)
}
```

My way is to add every `a` multiply **bits** of `b`.
Is there more efficient way to implement `Multiply`?

**Edit**

The [BESON](https://github.com/GoblinBear/beson-go) package represent a big number in byte array. For example, it represent a 128-bit unsigned interger in an byte array of size 16. Therefore, when doing two 128-bit unsigned interger multiplying, it's actually multiplying two byte array.

Example:

- input: `a`, `b`

```golang
a = []byte{ 204, 19, 46, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
b = []byte{ 117, 10, 68, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
Multiply(a, b)
fmt.Println(a)
```

- output: `a` (The result will write back to `a`)

```sh
[60 4 5 35 76 72 29 47]
```

Comment: Yes, there is. This is a problem for which a optimal solution was claimed a few days ago: David Harvey, Joris Van Der Hoeven. Integer multiplication in time O(n log n). 2019. <hal-02070778> But this solution is probably a) not useful for your code and b) out of your reach. You probably should peek into package math/big which uses non-optimal but fast multiplication (Karatsuba).

Comment: What do you mean by multiplying byte arrays ?. Can you give an example of your input and output.

Comment: I edited my question for more description and example.